# Is there an application to match and restore my stripped jpegs' dates to my original RAW dates?

Tags: metadata

I exported a bunch of RAW pics to jpeg manually, but all the metadata got stripped in the process (my mistake). Is there an application that can match the exported jpegs with the original RAW and restore the exif information, especially the dates?

Comment: If you've got the RAW files, you can re-export them

Comment: Thanks Laurence, but it's going to take a long time, because I have to edit them again and export them one by one. There are 135 of them

Comment: This is a pretty simple scripting problem if the filenames line up -- do they?

Comment: Yes, the filenames are the same

Comment: Would you mind saying that again, but slower this time. I'm sorry, I've never used scripting before

Comment: @user681768917 Would you also mind putting that in an answer where it belongs? [Short answers as comments — please resist the urge](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871)

Comment: @Moogal Why would you need to reedit them? Doesn't your raw conversion application save a list of your settings and editing steps?

Comment: @MichaelClark: Fixed, my comment answer deleted.

Comment: @Michael You're right. The application (Zoner) saves all the settings, but I still have to export them one by one, as far as I can see. There are over 500 pics to go through, and I need to export 135 because I'm not using all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a Windows user (or at least have an access to a Windows computer), place both RAWs and JPEGs to the same folder.

Install [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for your Windows version.

Open a command prompt
`Win-R` `cmd` and `cd` (change directory) to you folder.

Type:

```
exiftool tagsFromFile='%f.RAW' -ext jpg <directory_name>
```

The ExifTool copies the EXIF info from the RAW file to the jpeg file. You might want to play with its parameters. Besides the official manuals, [this thread](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=3440.0) might also help you.

Note 1: If your extension isn't RAW but NEF, PEF, CRW, RAF... change the command accordingly.
Note 2: The ExifTool is available also for Linux and MAC.

Comment: Exiftool can do this without the loop: exiftool tagsFromFile='%f.RAW' -ext jpg <directory_name>

Comment: The '%f' is an internal exiftool variable for the filename without extension, so it needs to be protected from expansion by the shell; on Windows it might need to be '%%f'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fiddled with it a bit and found this: exiftool -tagsfromfile %d%f.CR2 -r -ext JPG <dir> I found it at https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#COPYING-EXAMPLES